# Question about the Machine Room bridge in "Fringe"

Tags: fringe

In "Fringe" Season 4 Episode 18, as Olivia and Walter use the Machine Room bridge to cross over to the parallel world, they are "Scanned" by a bright light. What is that scan for ???

Answer (score 4):

A similar scan appeared in an earlier episode when Olivia and Nina Sharp were visiting a secure area in Massive Dynamic.

The purpose of such scans is to reveal hidden weaponry & bugging devices, verify identity, and possibly check for contagion.

Presumably, the ones in the bridge would also be scanning for shape shifters (the original kind).

They are the generic Sci-fi security scanners. They aren't explicitly explained in the show. Any answers will be (educated) speculation.

Comment: I haven't had time to rewatch the episode, but I think the previous episode with the scanning in Massive Dynamic was "Grey Matters", where the go to retrieve brain pieces. If not that episode, it was one where they went to MD to check on the Cortexiphan samples.